# Multiple Terms filters not working - Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to the DSL and im using the below json query:

```
    {
  "from": 0,
  "min_score": 0.5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "extension": [
              "bmp",
              "jpg",
              "tif",
              "img",
              "png",
              "gif",
              "jpeg"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "userContentType": [
              "webpage"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "language": [
              "en",
              "gen"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "metaLanguage": [
              "en"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "description^5",
              "partNumber",
              "guid",
              "metaId",
              "keywords"
            ],
            "lenient": true,
            "query": "technology"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "userContentType.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I get no results. However if I take out one of the terms, say 'extension' or 'userContentType' it works fine and I get the expected results..
I figure it's somthing to do with using multiple terms inside a filter, but not sure why that would cause an issue also.
I've tried removing the 'should' and 'min_score' but it made no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Index mappings:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "applicationName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "createdDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "extension": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "industryCategoryIdentifiers": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "keywords": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "language": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "metaLanguage": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "pageId": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "productLineCategoryIdentifiers": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "updatedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "userContentType": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your index mapping as well?

Comment: Gladly, just not sure how to do that sorry. 
Also I forgot to mention that 'extension' and 'userContentType' are both string values in the indexes (3)

Comment: simply `GET your-index-name` in Kibana Dev Tools and copy/paster the output in your question

Comment: Updated. Im using Elastic search head extension for Edge, so apologies if it doesn't look like what your expecting.

Answer (score 0):

According to your mapping you need to use the `keyword` subfield, like this:

```
    {
      "terms": {
        "extension.keyword": [
          "bmp",
          "jpg",
          "tif",
          "img",
          "png",
          "gif",
          "jpeg"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "terms": {
        "userContentType.keyword": [
          "webpage"
        ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: Updated the terms to have the .keyword but still no results.

Comment: Can you show a sample document that you think should match?

Comment: We use multiple indexes, one for webpages, media and ecommerce. 
Essentially what im trying to achieve is searching on doc's and getting results that contain  both webpages and media for a given query phrase. 
So in the example above ive searched for phrase cmm, and I want to view everything that is media images (extension) and webpage (usercontenttype).
I know for certain there are cmm images and webpages, but at the moment I can only search one or the other...it's as if the query is doing an AND rather than an OR

Comment: Update: If I use - 
 "terms": {
            "extension": [
              "bmp",
              "jpg",
              "tif",
              "img",
              "png",
              "gif",
              "jpeg"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "extension": [
              "aspx"
            ]
          }
        },

it works as expected.. Not sure why. Seems I can only use a certain number of terms maybe

Comment: Ok, I see, the fact that you're querying multiple indexes doesn't give you the guarantee that you'll get results from each index in the same response. You need to issue the same request over the three indexes (using _msearch maybe) so that you can get results from each index

Comment: I pass through a collection of indexes (via the NEST dsl) to search, so if im searching with just a phrase and filter I get results from each index.